# using Dropxbox in MVC 5app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, dropbox-api

I have a requirement in my MVC 5 App where i need to upload some images on      dropbox and save their path in my db .
 Please suggest me any API which is good and have some good code samples.

The requirement is like I have a page   from which admin add some photos in gallery, those pics should be saved in dropbox and their path is save in db.
i have search our many codes but could'nt get any.

Comment: Check their api documentation. https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: they dont have any code examples there

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207908343-uploading-image-to-dropbox-from-asp-net-mvc-app-and-save-it-s-path-in-db ]